# Husky, git, detect new code and file extensions (for test)

Tags: git, husky, git-husky

It's a very custom question, but maybe someone has the answer or has been in this scenario.

Is there a way to specify (maybe with Husky) that if some new file has been added in some folder, then the PR need to have an specific file extension too?

My idea is:

```
- If the PR includes code in the path "/utils" then
  - the PR it must contains a ".test.js" file
```

I want to force that if someone has created new code under "/utils" path then is mandatory to upload a new ".test.js" file

Comment: any solution???

Comment: No, haven't found a way to do it